# Magento 2: How to add a custom js file before end of body tag in CMS page

Tags: javascript, magento2

The Magento documentation does not cover this basic functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below steps for adding custom js before the body tag

Step 1 : Add below layout code into *myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="You_Module::js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Step 2 : Add custom.js in js.phtml file like below.

`<script src="example.com/jp2/test.js" />`